# How can I have a writable text box?

Tags: java, swing

Using pure java, I would like to have a player press a JButton, have a text box pop up which they can type in, and then have a certain action happen when the player presses "Enter".

How could I do this?

I have not yet attempted this because I do not know where to start, however my current code is

```
package Joehot200;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;

public class Main extends JFrame {
static boolean start = false;
private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
static Main frame = null;
String version = "0.4";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                frame = new Main();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setTitle("Privateers");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    TerrainDemo.startGame();
}
boolean cantConnect = false;
/**
 * Create the frame.
 */

public Main() {
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    final JButton btnEnterBattlefield =  new JButton("Enter battlefield!"); 
    btnEnterBattlefield.setForeground(Color.red);
    //btnEnterBattlefield.setBackground(Color.green);
    //btnEnterBattlefield.setOpaque(true);
    menuBar.add(btnEnterBattlefield);
    btnEnterBattlefield.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Execute when button is pressed
             System.out.println(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "res/images/heightmap.bmp").getAbsolutePath());
            //System.out.println("You clicked the button");
             if (cantConnect){
                 btnEnterBattlefield.setText("Unable to connect to the server!");
             }else{
                 btnEnterBattlefield.setText("Connecting to server...");
             }
            start = true;
        } 
    });      

    //JMenu mnLogIn = new JMenu("Log in");
    JMenu mnLogIn = new JMenu("Currently useless button");
    mnLogIn.setForeground(Color.magenta);
    menuBar.add(mnLogIn);

    JButton btnLogIntoGame = new JButton("Log into game.");
    mnLogIn.add(btnLogIntoGame);

    JButton btnRegisterNewAccount = new JButton("Register new account");
    mnLogIn.add(btnRegisterNewAccount);
    final JButton btnGoToWebsite = new JButton("We currently do not but soon will have a website.");
    btnGoToWebsite.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        //btnGoToWebsite = new JButton("Go to website.");
    btnGoToWebsite.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Execute when button is pressed
            System.out.println("Going to website!");
                try {
                    java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("www.endcraft.net/none"));
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    btnGoToWebsite.setText("Error going to website!");
                }
        }
    });      
    menuBar.add(btnGoToWebsite);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    FlowLayout flowLayout = (FlowLayout) contentPane.getLayout();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    //contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/res/background.png");
    Image img = icon.getImage() ;  
       Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance(this.getWidth()*3, this.getHeight()*3,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH ) ;  
       icon = new ImageIcon( newimg );
      JLabel background=new JLabel(icon);

        getContentPane().add(background);

        background.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    //JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    //contentPane.add(progressBar);

    //JMenu mnWelcomeToA = new JMenu("Welcome to a pirate game!");
    //contentPane.add(mnWelcomeToA);

    //JButton btnStartGame = new JButton("Start game");
    //mnWelcomeToA.add(btnStartGame);

    //JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();
    //mnWelcomeToA.add(splitPane);

    //JButton btnRegister = new JButton("Register");
    //splitPane.setLeftComponent(btnRegister);

    //JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
    //splitPane.setRightComponent(btnLogin);


}


}
```

It is the "Register account" and "Log into game" button that I would like to have the above described action happen on.

Would be great if someone could tell me how to do this.

Comment: `JTextField` or `JTextArea` are the objetcs you need.

Comment: have you looked at JOptionPane?

Comment: @Jens But how can I have them appear after a button is pressed, and how can I make something happen when I press "Enter"?

And thanks, that is about a quarter of my question answered :).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you decide to implement a new frame (not best practice), with a new panel, and the JTextField or JTextArea within, you must bind a listener to the button that calls `setVisible()` on the newly created frame..
For example:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    yourFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Further, you could create the frame everytime the button is clicked, within the actionPerformed method aswell, however this is also not best practice..

A better alternative may be to implement a JOptionPane, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) or [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)..

Comment: Thanks to you and the two people in the comments. All your answers have been very helpful.